# Probability of a number N being reduced to a nonpositive value after K trials

Tags: java, python, algorithm, permutation, probability

Let's say we have an integer `N`. In each of `K` trials, that number is reduced by a random integer number from the uniform interval `[0, M]` (so if we had `M = 5`, then a number `N` in each trial could be reduced by either `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5`, each with a probability `1/6`). What is the probability that the number `N` will be less than or equal to zero after `K` trials? As an example, for `N=2`, `M=1` and `K=3` the answer is `0.5`.

I could write the brute force solution that would simply enumerate every permutation for a total of `(M+1)^K` and count cases when `N` ends up being `<= 0` having subtracted all the numbers from it in the given permutation. But for this problem, `M` and `K` could be up to 1000, and then this complexity becomes `1000^(1000)` which is intractable.

So I was wondering if there is some math formula that could help me avoid generating all the permutations?

Comment: I see, so I would just subtract that resulting probability from 1 to get my result. And `c0, c1, ... ci` correspond to the integers in the range `[0, M]`, right? And the denominator is basically `N^K`, right?

Comment: Hmm, I see, I see. I just wonder how to generalize the numerator to the case when `M > 1`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a program to calculate the required probability

```py
N = 2
M = 1
K = 3

count = [0] * (N+1)
prev = [0] * (N+1)

count[0] = 1 # empty set

for i in range(K):
    # move count to prev
    for index in range(N+1):
        prev[index] = count[index]
        count[index] = 0
    
    # calculate new counts
    for prevSum in range(N+1):
        for value in range(M+1):
            newSum = min(N, prevSum+value)
            count[newSum] += prev[prevSum]
            
ans = (count[N] / pow(M+1, K))
print(ans)
```

[working code link](https://ideone.com/5N9fHj)

- Here we keep track of the count of number of sets that add upto a given sum in the `count[]` array
- Any set that adds upto a value greater than `N` is added to `count[N]`

How does this work?

- Initially, `count[0] = 1`, since we only have empty set `{}`
- (K = 1): try adding one element to all the existing sets: `{} + 0, {} + 1`. we get `{0}, {1}` so `count[0] = 1`, `count[1] = 1`
- (K = 2): Now again add one element to all the existing sets: `{0} + 0, {0} + 1, {1} + 0, {1} + 1`. we get `{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}` so `count[0] = 1`, `count[1] = 2`, `count[2] = 1`
- (K = 3): Now again add one element to all the existing sets. We would get `{0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,1,0}, {1,0,0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,1,0}, {1,1,1}`.
  so `count[0] = 1`, `count[1] = 3`, `count[2] = 4`
- here in the last step, we also add `{1,1,1}` to `count[2]` because we add all sets whose sum is `>= N` to `count[N]`
- Finally, to compute the probability we divide `count[N]`(count of all sets whose sum is `>=N`) with the count of all possible sets i.e, `(M+1)^K`

The complexity is `O(N*M*K)`. In worst case `N=M*K`, so the time complexity can be rewritten as: `O((M*K)^2)`

---

Optimisation 1:

If you write down the `count[]` array for each iteration of `K` you can find an interesting observation:

```
M=1

sum: 0 1 2 3 4
K=0: 1 0 0 0 0 (if empty consider value as 0 from now on)
K=1: 1 1
K=2: 1 2 1
K=3: 1 3 3 1
K=4: 1 4 6 4 1


M=2

sum: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
K=0: 1
K=1: 1  1  1
K=2: 1  2  3  2  1
K=3: 1  3  6  7  6  3  1
K=4: 1  4 10 16 19 16 10  4  1
```

the observation here is: [image: formula]

By maintaining a rolling sum of previous M values, we can write optimised version of the code:

```py
N = 2
M = 1
K = 3
maxValue = M*K

count = [0] * (maxValue+1)
prev = [0] * (maxValue+1)

count[0] = 1 # empty set

for i in range(K):
    # move count to prev
    for index in range(maxValue+1):
        prev[index] = count[index]
        count[index] = 0
    
    rollingSum = 0
    
    # calculate new counts
    for Sum in range(maxValue+1):
        rollingSum += prev[Sum]
        if (Sum > M):
            rollingSum -= prev[Sum - (M + 1)]
        count[Sum] = rollingSum
            

# add all counts of sets whose sum is >= N
ans = sum(count[N:]) / pow(M+1,K)
print(ans)
```

[working code link](https://ideone.com/zuDTvi)

The time complexity of this approach is `O(M*(K^2))`

Comment: Worst case for N is `M*K`, and OP says M and K can be up to 1000, so we're looking at O(10^12) worst case. Maybe I shouldn't have deleted my comments under the OP. I thought this was faster than it is. But have an upvote anyways :)

Comment: I wanted to read your comments after editing my answer but found them deleted. You can maybe add them back or feel free to edit this answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the comments, and there's no undo button after deleting comments. The general idea was to solve the [composition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) and then assign a probability to each composition using [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: @user3386109 added an optimisation that reduces it to O(10^9)

Comment: That's an interesting observation. And O(10^9) means this will run in a few seconds even worst case. Very impressive! I'd give you another upvote if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

I will focus at the algorithm level only here.

The problem is equivalent to calculate the probability than after K steps, the sum of the values is greater than N.

Let ut call `p` the probability that at a given step, on element is selected

```
p = 1/(M+1)
```

The idea is to represent the probability set of one trial in a polynomial form:

```
A[x] = p * (1 + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^{M-1})
```

Then after `K` steps, the probability set is given by:

```
F[x] = p^K * (1 + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^{M-1})^K = p^K A[x]^K
```

At the end, if `F[x] = sum_i p_i x^i`, then the probability is given by:

```
P = sum_{i >= N} p_i
```

The problem is then to calculate the polynomial power `A[x]^k`.

A **first attempt** consits in
calculating it recursively: then we obtained something equivalent to be solution provided in the first answer, same complexity.

A **second attempt** consist in implicitely considering the binary representation of `K`.

Pseudo-code:

```
F[x] = 1
T[x] = A[x]
Power = K
while (Power != 0)
    if (Power mod 2 == 1) F[x] = F[x] * T[x]
    T[x] = T[x] * T[x]
    Power = Power / 2
end while
```

The number of steps is equel to `log2(K)`.
At each iteration, the degree of the polynomial is multiplied by two: the complexity is dominated by the last step,
where the order of the polynomial is equal to `KM`.
This last step has a complexity `O(K^2 M^2)`.

If `C = K^2 M^2`, The global complexity of the power calculation is `O(C + C/4 + C/8 + ...) = O(C) = O(K^2M^2)`.

This method doesn't seem to provide any advantage with respect to the first one (I may have made an error in the complexity evaluation!).

A **third method** consists in considering that a polynomial multiplication is equivalent to a convolution, and can be performed via a FFT process. As the final size is O(KM), then the complexity is `O(M K (log M + log K))`.

Describing this method in details here would take much time. You could find many references
on internet on this subject, for example [here](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/%7Ecs577/handouts/polymultiply.pdf)

---

Side note: a pity not being able to insert latex math formula here ...